# Date picker (overlay) top section is hiding due to space issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Issue:**
Date picker (overlay) top section is hiding due to space issue. (See attachment)

**Expected behaviour:**
If available space is less than automatically date picker (overlay) should shift and show full UI.

**Current behaviour:**
https://v6.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

**Angular Material Version: 6.4.7,
Browser: Chrome,
Operating System : Windows**

[image: Angular Material Date Picker Issue Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

it's a known issue with material datepicker. you can use below selector in main stayle file to target and add your custom styles, for example:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane.mat-datepicker-popup{
overflow: overflow: scroll;
/* other styles goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with later versions of angular. If possible I would recommend to upgrade